# How to add another <dt> on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting a form of ingredients with unfixed number.
I want the user to be able to add another dt to the list on client side.

to code is:

```
<form> 
 <form>
  <dl>
    <dt >
      <input type="text"/>
    </dt>
    <dt >
      <button type="button" onClick="??"/>
    </dt>
  </dl>
</form>
```

Is there a way to add dt on the client side when the button is press?

Comment: What languages are you using?

Comment: Why are you using a definition list for things which are not definitions?

Comment: And why are there two `<form>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<form>
 <dl id="appendHere">
  <dt >
   <input type="text"/>
  </dt>
  <dt >
   <button type="button" onClick="doAppend();"/>
  </dt>
</dl>
</form>
<script>
var forIndexing = 0;
function doAppend(){
 var newIn = document.createElement("dt");
 newIn.innerHTML = '<input id="someId' + forIndexing + '" type="text"/>';
 forIndexing++;
 var newdt = document.createElement("dt");
 newdt.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="doAppend();"/>';
 document.getElementById("appendHere").appendChild(newIn);
 document.getElementById("appendHere").appendChild(newdt);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, my JS background is limited. How can i differ the name of the input every time i add one for getting the parameters separated?

Comment: You will note the indexing integer added in the answer.